# Unable to read data continously using BLE pygatt call back function

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I am currently working on BLE in raspberry pi cm4 using Pygatt library, I am able to subscribe and able to call back the notify handler in which i am reading the data but i want a continous stream of data instead i am getting data for only 2 to 3 seconds and it automatically stops here. Please help me out

Comment: You have not shared any code or debug information so it is going to be difficult for other people to help. When running your script have separate terminals open with the following running to get more debug information:

`bluetootctl`, 
`journalctl -f -u bluetooth`, 
`sudo busctl monitor org.bluez`, 
`sudo btmon`

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same question. Adding "auto_reconnect=True" in function "adapter.connect()" can solve the question. It can continously receive data when reconnect is done.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31176218)